# How to determine a good centre for a zoom on the Mandelbrot set

Tags: c++, math, graphics, cuda

I just finished writing a cuda program which renders images of the Mandelbrot set.  The way I have it set up is that you pass the function which creates the image a scale which is pixels per unit and the x and y coordinates of the centre of the image in the complex plane.  I want to create a deep zoom movie from many frames and I need my program to be able to automatically determine a centre where "interesting" stuff will be happening (not zooming in on a region which will just be all one colour).  How should I pick the coordinate to zoom into.

Here is my code if anyone is interested.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/complex.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>

typedef double real;

inline void cuda_error(cudaError_t code, const char* lbl)
{
    if(code != cudaSuccess)
    {
        std::cerr << lbl << " : " << cudaGetErrorString(code) << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}

__global__ void mandelbrot_kernel(unsigned char* pix, real cx, real cy, real pix_scale, size_t w, size_t h, int iters)
{
    cy = -cy;
    real sx = cx - (w * pix_scale) / 2;
    real sy = cy - (w * pix_scale) / 2;

    size_t x = (size_t)blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    size_t y = (size_t)blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    if(x >= w || y >= h)
        return;

    thrust::complex<real> c(sx + pix_scale * x, sy + pix_scale * y);
    thrust::complex<real> z(0, 0);
    int i = 0;
    for(; i < iters && thrust::abs(z) < 2; ++i)
        z = z * z + c;

    real scale = 255.0 / (real)iters;
    size_t q = 3 * (w * y + x);
    pix[q] = i * scale;
    pix[q + 1] = 255 * sinf(z.imag());
    pix[q + 2] = 255 * sinf(z.real());
}

void shade_mandelbrot(unsigned char* pix, real* devs, real cx, real cy, real pix_scale, int w, int h, int iters)
{
    dim3 blockDim(16, 16);
    dim3 gridDim((w + 15) / 16, (h + 15) / 16);
    mandelbrot_kernel<<<gridDim, blockDim>>>(pix, cx, cy, pix_scale, w, h, iters);
}

void ppm_write(FILE* f, unsigned char* pix, int w, int h)
{
    assert(fprintf(f, "P6 %d %d 255\n", w, h) > 0);
    size_t sz = 3 * (size_t)w * (size_t)h;
    assert(fwrite(pix, 1, sz, f) == sz);
}

int main()
{
    int dim = 2000;
    int w = dim;
    int h = dim;
    int imgs = 200;
    int iters = 1024;

    real cx = -0.7463, cy = 0.1102;
    cuda_error(cudaSetDevice(0), "Set Device");
    unsigned char* pix_buffers[2];
    real* dev_buffers[2];

    cuda_error(cudaHostAlloc(pix_buffers, 3 * sizeof(unsigned char) * w * h, 0), "Host Alloc 1");
    cuda_error(cudaHostAlloc(pix_buffers + 1, 3 * sizeof(unsigned char) * w * h, 0), "Host Alloc 2");

    real scale = 8.0 / w;
    shade_mandelbrot(pix_buffers[0], dev_buffers[0], cx, cy, scale, w, h, iters);
    for(int i = 0; i < imgs; i++)
    {
        cuda_error(cudaDeviceSynchronize(), "Sync");

        std::cout << scale << std::endl;
        if(i < (imgs - 1))
            shade_mandelbrot(pix_buffers[(i + 1) % 2], dev_buffers[(i + 1) % 2], cx, cy, scale *= 0.97, w, h, 255);
        char fn[100];
        sprintf(fn, "/media/chase/3161D67803D8C5BE/Mandelbroght/image%06d.ppm", i);
        puts(fn);
        FILE* f = fopen(fn, "w");
        assert(f);

        ppm_write(f, pix_buffers[i % 2], w, h);
        fclose(f);
    }


    cuda_error(cudaFreeHost(pix_buffers[0]), "Host Free 1");
    cuda_error(cudaFreeHost(pix_buffers[1]), "Host Free 2");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Points with a high iteration count (but not equal to `iters`) when exiting the inner loop will present interesting behavior because they are close to the set boundary. You could just pick points in random, run it through the algorithm and use the point with the highest count as the center. You may get results faster if you pick a few points in random, take the point with the highest iteration count, generate a few points around it, see if you get an even higher iteration count, and repeat with the best of those points.

Answer (score 1):

Well I came up with an idea which works really well.  What I do I calculate the entropy for each 16x16 square in the image.  I then just zoom into the the area with the maximum entropy for that image.

```
__global__ void entropy_kernel(unsigned char* pix, float* entropy, size_t w, size_t h)
{
    __shared__ float probs[256];
    __shared__ float e;

    if(threadIdx.x == 0 && threadIdx.y == 0)
    {
        e = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
            probs[i] = 0;
    }

    __syncthreads();

    int x = blockIdx.x * ENTROPY_BLOCK_DIM + threadIdx.x;
    int y = blockIdx.y * ENTROPY_BLOCK_DIM + threadIdx.y;
    int px = pix[3 * (y * w + x)];
    float p = 1.0 / (float)(ENTROPY_BLOCK_DIM * ENTROPY_BLOCK_DIM);
    atomicAdd(probs + px, p);

    __syncthreads();

    p = probs[px];
    if(p) atomicAdd(&e, p * log10f(p));

    __syncthreads();

    if(threadIdx.x == 0 && threadIdx.y == 0)
    {
        entropy[blockIdx.y * gridDim.x + blockIdx.x] = -e;
    }
}
```

Here is how it turned out.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mtxbdoJBA0Q

Comment: Beautiful animation, but the changes in direction made me dizzy. Maybe it would be better to use your entropy idea on a first pass to choose the final destination, then rerun a zoom that just smoothly zooms in on that point.